# How can I stop a Javascript from being interpreted after a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

The first few lines of my script look like:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}
```

I'd like to have the entire script "skipped" if this statement returns true.  Is there any way to do this other than putting my entire script in a giant if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    return;
}
```

Note that the script will still be *parsed* until the end, so it has to be valid JavaScript all the way through. But I think you meant "interpreted" in the title.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, interpreted is what I meant.